# Zend framework compatiable twitter, facebook ,myspace API

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, twitter, myspace

Can any one give me Link for API's to post messages over  twitter, facebook ,myspace  social media 
using zend framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one for twitter, http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html, you will have to build the others yourself